# httpd Process Using High CPU (And Seems To Be Loading All Log Files)

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

This is causing my server to crash every single day. See processes and files loaded below. Thanks in advance!

When I do "**top**":

```
    20034 apache    20   0  441m  98m 7004 R 99.5  1.5   0:48.58 httpd
20128 apache    20   0  428m  85m 5268 S 33.3  1.4   0:07.89 httpd
 1219 mysql     20   0  529m 228m 7820 S  0.7  3.6  39:34.34 mysqld
    1 root      20   0 10324  672  616 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.41 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/85623
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/85623
  128 root      16  -4 12592  400  396 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
  556 root      20   0  5932  588  516 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.76 syslogd
  565 dbus      20   0 21236  812  672 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon
  573 haldaemo  20   0 30156 3208 1592 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hald
  574 root      20   0 21724 1188 1008 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hald-runner
  615 sw-cp-se  20   0 65128 8176 1416 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.36 sw-cp-serverd
  629 root      20   0 64752 1204  636 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.46 sshd
  637 root      20   0 21616  860  724 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.57 xinetd
  652 root      20   0 13196  568  484 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 couriertcpd
  654 root      20   0  3812  560  468 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 courierlogger
  662 root      20   0 13196  608  480 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  664 root      20   0  3680  380  308 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 courierlogger
  670 root      20   0 13196  548  484 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 couriertcpd
  672 root      20   0  3812  536  468 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 courierlogger
  679 root      20   0 13196  620  484 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 couriertcpd
  681 root      20   0  3812  560  468 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 courierlogger
  691 qmails    20   0  3868  492  376 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.32 qmail-send
  693 qmaill    20   0  3820  552  460 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 splogger
  694 root      20   0  3860  456  336 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 qmail-lspawn
  695 qmailr    20   0  3860  468  340 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 qmail-rspawn
  696 qmailq    20   0  3816  428  336 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 qmail-clean
```

Then when I "**lsof -p [pid]**":

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
httpd   20034 apache  cwd    DIR               0,50     4096    1557805 /var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/httpdocs/wp-admin
httpd   20034 apache  rtd    DIR               0,50     4096    1050935 /
httpd   20034 apache  txt    REG               0,50   465024    4213124 /usr/sbin/httpd
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    23736    4374835 /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG             144,49          4137329561 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG             144,49          4137329554 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    90664    3701688 /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    12944    1861553 /usr/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.3.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   465968    1861404 /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.2
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   217592    1861511 /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1.1.17
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    73352    1861607 /usr/lib64/libexslt.so.0.8.13
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    33848    3701683 /usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    44824    3701694 /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlwriter.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    75640    3701691 /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlrpc.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    30104    3701680 /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    32600    3701675 /usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   324464    3701686 /usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    35072    4374887 /lib64/libwrap.so.0.7.6
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   606352    1861660 /usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.10.0.3
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    54000    3701676 /usr/lib64/php/modules/snmp.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   258272    3701672 /usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   576008    1861576 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    24872    3701692 /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    24072    3701684 /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_odbc.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    32744    3701697 /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    98536    3701681 /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   409128    1861272 /usr/lib64/libodbc.so.1.0.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    61528    3701677 /usr/lib64/php/modules/odbc.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   135688    3701673 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    56072    4379847 /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   973680    1861412 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50  2969984    3701459 /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    50840    3701696 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    27656    1861546 /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.3.1.4
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   177784    1861524 /usr/lib64/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    41320    3701679 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50  1283536    3701678 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mbstring.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    53272    3701685 /usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    37624    3701693 /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    96600    4374859 /lib64/libaudit.so.0.0.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    44472    4374865 /lib64/libpam.so.0.81.5
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   865824    1861101 /usr/lib64/libc-client.so.1
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    95608    3701674 /usr/lib64/php/modules/imap.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    19768    1861143 /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     9776    1861428 /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   136672    1861700 /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   147024    1861200 /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0.10.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50    69216    1861521 /usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4.11.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50  1097400    1861681 /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.2.0
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   541560    1861414 /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.3.10
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   282856    1861646 /usr/lib64/libt1.so.5.1.2
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50   327136    3701695 /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50  2701824    3701682 /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so

httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     7040    3701739 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_user.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     9344    3701721 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     6048    3701743 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_default.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     7232    3701752 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     7200    3701746 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_anon.so
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG               0,50     8064    3701720
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG             144,49                   0 (deleted)/VE85623-SYSV013201f4 (stat: No such file or directory)
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG             144,49          4137329335 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
httpd   20034 apache  mem    REG             144,49          4137329334 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
httpd   20034 apache    0r   CHR                1,3      0t0 4137321857 /dev/null
httpd   20034 apache    1w   CHR                1,3      0t0 4137321857 /dev/null
httpd   20034 apache    2w   REG               0,50    64902    1327286 /var/log/httpd/error_log
httpd   20034 apache    3r   CHR                1,9      0t0 4137321927 /dev/urandom
httpd   20034 apache    4u  IPv4         4137328741      0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   20034 apache    5u  IPv4         4137328743      0t0        TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   20034 apache    6r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 4137329325 pipe
httpd   20034 apache    7w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 4137329325 pipe
httpd   20034 apache    8w   REG               0,50 11797533    1316311 /var/log/atmail/error_log
httpd   20034 apache    9w   REG               0,50     8879    1326518 /var/www/vhosts/falcontheater.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   10w   REG               0,50   486489    5008323 /var/www/vhosts/housemedic.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   11w   REG               0,50    21242    1330337 /var/www/vhosts/hexsee.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   12w   REG               0,50 42684872    1611780 /var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   13w   REG               0,50   545243    5007917 /var/www/vhosts/fdt.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   14w   REG               0,50  1195760    1412990 /var/www/vhosts/gtc.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   15w   REG               0,50   825936    1427501 /var/www/vhosts/bcvc.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   16w   REG               0,50    16214    1327023 /var/www/vhosts/tfa.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   17w   REG               0,50    23401    1397660 /var/www/vhosts/testing.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   18w   REG               0,50   883503    4745800 /var/www/vhosts/mma.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   19w   REG               0,50    96250    1347445 /var/www/vhosts/plugins.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   20w   REG               0,50    21480    4376516 /var/www/vhosts/plugins.ideasandpixels.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   21w   REG               0,50  6136317    1342169 /var/www/vhosts/theiotaproject.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   22w   REG               0,50    25453    1371496 /var/www/vhosts/sag.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   23w   REG               0,50    26302    4377027 /var/www/vhosts/dreamhoneymoon-old.net/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   24w   REG               0,50  1174247    1617992 /var/www/vhosts/floorsbyvalvano.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   25w   REG               0,50 14310312    5305744 /var/www/vhosts/fdtcincinnati.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   26w   REG               0,50    51792    1333246 /var/www/vhosts/tripleepartners.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   27w   REG               0,50    33187    4981662 /var/www/vhosts/tuv.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   28w   REG               0,50   126316    1632702 /var/www/vhosts/clarkschaefer.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   29w   REG               0,50 30446627    1404518 /var/www/vhosts/dreamhoneymoon.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   30w   REG               0,50    77742    4473148 /var/www/vhosts/affordable-contractors.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   31w   REG               0,50   176507    4856845 /var/www/vhosts/eagletee.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   32w   REG               0,50    82571    4993090 /var/www/vhosts/rx4p.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   33w   REG               0,50   244491    1421733 /var/www/vhosts/epic-resale.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   34w   REG               0,50    96077    1417205 /var/www/vhosts/skullintheashes.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   35w   REG               0,50   146214    4612141 /var/www/vhosts/darksaintstudios.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   36w   REG               0,50  8365086    1369146 /var/www/vhosts/roygingrich.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   37w   REG               0,50 42924335    1380726 /var/www/vhosts/lampmaster.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   38w   REG               0,50    56683    4615281 /var/www/vhosts/sam.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   39w   REG               0,50   127250    1364762 /var/www/vhosts/navettadesign.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   40w   REG               0,50    69007    1628758 /var/www/vhosts/caroftheday.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   41w   REG               0,50   107906    5003138 /var/www/vhosts/delhisalon.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   42w   REG               0,50   707422    4470467 /var/www/vhosts/pukpipe.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   43w   REG               0,50   283087    1344300 /var/www/vhosts/answeringserviceconsultants.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   44w   REG               0,50   111357    1399774 /var/www/vhosts/bjelectrical.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   45w   REG               0,50  3064671    1414499 /var/www/vhosts/thedailydiscourse.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   46w   REG               0,50   501209    4614795 /var/www/vhosts/test.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   47w   REG               0,50   135302    5114478 /var/www/vhosts/valvanocarpeting.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   48w   REG               0,50   165349    5000681 /var/www/vhosts/ip.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   49w   REG               0,50   303555    1407572 /var/www/vhosts/cincyartgroup.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   50w   REG               0,50   563811    1395401 /var/www/vhosts/chicagolandanswering.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   51w   REG               0,50   324140    4614239 /var/www/vhosts/atcanswers.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   52w   REG               0,50   541196    1333947 /var/www/vhosts/iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   53w   REG               0,50  7250655    1392178 /var/www/vhosts/ideasandpixels.com/statistics/logs/error_log
httpd   20034 apache   54w   REG               0,50      555    1342514 /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log
httpd   20034 apache   55w   REG               0,50    54616    1316717 /var/log/httpd/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   56w   REG               0,50 12296884    1316722 /var/log/atmail/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   57w   REG               0,50 12296884    1316722 /var/log/atmail/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   58w   REG               0,50        0    1326568 /var/www/vhosts/falcontheater.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   59w   REG               0,50        0    1326515 /var/www/vhosts/falcontheater.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   60w   REG               0,50   302668    5008373 /var/www/vhosts/housemedic.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   61w   REG               0,50    21925    5008319 /var/www/vhosts/housemedic.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   62w   REG               0,50        0    1330386 /var/www/vhosts/hexsee.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   63w   REG               0,50        0    1330334 /var/www/vhosts/hexsee.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   64w   REG               0,50   637920    1611844 /var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   65w   REG               0,50   637920    1611844 /var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   66w   REG               0,50 10219707    1611793 /var/www/vhosts/housedoctors.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   67w   REG               0,50     1774    5007967 /var/www/vhosts/fdt.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   68w   REG               0,50        0    5007914 /var/www/vhosts/fdt.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   69w   REG               0,50   362088    1413041 /var/www/vhosts/gtc.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   70w   REG               0,50        0    1412987 /var/www/vhosts/gtc.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   71w   REG               0,50      682    1427550 /var/www/vhosts/bcvc.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   72w   REG               0,50        0    1427499 /var/www/vhosts/bcvc.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   73w   REG               0,50        0    1327071 /var/www/vhosts/tfa.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   74w   REG               0,50        0    1327021 /var/www/vhosts/tfa.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   75w   REG               0,50        0    1397705 /var/www/vhosts/testing.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   76w   REG               0,50        0    1397657 /var/www/vhosts/testing.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   77w   REG               0,50        0    4745853 /var/www/vhosts/mma.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   78w   REG               0,50        0    4745797 /var/www/vhosts/mma.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   79w   REG               0,50     2256    1347493 /var/www/vhosts/plugins.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   80w   REG               0,50        0    1347442 /var/www/vhosts/plugins.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   81w   REG               0,50        0    4376565 /var/www/vhosts/plugins.ideasandpixels.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   82w   REG               0,50        0    4376513 /var/www/vhosts/plugins.ideasandpixels.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   83w   REG               0,50  1258454    1342220 /var/www/vhosts/theiotaproject.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   84w   REG               0,50        0    1342163 /var/www/vhosts/theiotaproject.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   85w   REG               0,50        0    1371542 /var/www/vhosts/sag.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   86w   REG               0,50        0    1371493 /var/www/vhosts/sag.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   87w   REG               0,50        0    4377075 /var/www/vhosts/dreamhoneymoon-old.net/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   88w   REG               0,50        0    4377025 /var/www/vhosts/dreamhoneymoon-old.net/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   89w   REG               0,50   196194    1618043 /var/www/vhosts/floorsbyvalvano.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   90w   REG               0,50        0    1617991 /var/www/vhosts/floorsbyvalvano.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   91w   REG               0,50  1721189    5305796 /var/www/vhosts/fdtcincinnati.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   92w   REG               0,50        0    5305742 /var/www/vhosts/fdtcincinnati.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   93w   REG               0,50   220651    1333300 /var/www/vhosts/tripleepartners.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   94w   REG               0,50        0    1333244 /var/www/vhosts/tripleepartners.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   95w   REG               0,50        0    4981714 /var/www/vhosts/tuv.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   96w   REG               0,50        0    4981659 /var/www/vhosts/tuv.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   97w   REG               0,50   160314    1632758 /var/www/vhosts/clarkschaefer.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache   98w   REG               0,50        0    1632701 /var/www/vhosts/clarkschaefer.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache   99w   REG               0,50   300490    1404576 /var/www/vhosts/dreamhoneymoon.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  100w   REG               0,50    39674    1404512 /var/www/vhosts/dreamhoneymoon.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  101w   REG               0,50    41455    4473200 /var/www/vhosts/affordable-contractors.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  102w   REG               0,50        0    4473146 /var/www/vhosts/affordable-contractors.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  103w   REG               0,50   242518    4856904 /var/www/vhosts/eagletee.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  104w   REG               0,50        0    4856833 /var/www/vhosts/eagletee.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  105w   REG               0,50        0    4993141 /var/www/vhosts/rx4p.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  106w   REG               0,50        0    4993087 /var/www/vhosts/rx4p.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  107w   REG               0,50   162787    1421781 /var/www/vhosts/epic-resale.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  108w   REG               0,50        0    1421732 /var/www/vhosts/epic-resale.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  109w   REG               0,50        0    1418035 /var/www/vhosts/skullintheashes.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  110w   REG               0,50        0    1417202 /var/www/vhosts/skullintheashes.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  111w   REG               0,50    40306    4612192 /var/www/vhosts/darksaintstudios.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  112w   REG               0,50        0    4612138 /var/www/vhosts/darksaintstudios.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  113w   REG               0,50    33071    1369197 /var/www/vhosts/roygingrich.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  114w   REG               0,50        0    1369141 /var/www/vhosts/roygingrich.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  115w   REG               0,50   687012    1380791 /var/www/vhosts/lampmaster.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  116w   REG               0,50   687012    1380791 /var/www/vhosts/lampmaster.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  117w   REG               0,50    53882    1380725 /var/www/vhosts/lampmaster.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  118w   REG               0,50        0    4615330 /var/www/vhosts/sam.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  119w   REG               0,50        0    4615278 /var/www/vhosts/sam.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  120w   REG               0,50  1131520    1364816 /var/www/vhosts/navettadesign.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  121w   REG               0,50        0    1364761 /var/www/vhosts/navettadesign.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  122w   REG               0,50      346    1628806 /var/www/vhosts/caroftheday.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  123w   REG               0,50        0    1628755 /var/www/vhosts/caroftheday.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  124w   REG               0,50    85541    5003191 /var/www/vhosts/delhisalon.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  125w   REG               0,50        0    5003136 /var/www/vhosts/delhisalon.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  126w   REG               0,50   870413    4470536 /var/www/vhosts/pukpipe.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  127w   REG               0,50    65705    4470474 /var/www/vhosts/pukpipe.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  128w   REG               0,50        0    1344349 /var/www/vhosts/answeringserviceconsultants.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  129w   REG               0,50        0    1344297 /var/www/vhosts/answeringserviceconsultants.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  130w   REG               0,50    71550    1399826 /var/www/vhosts/bjelectrical.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  131w   REG               0,50        0    1399772 /var/www/vhosts/bjelectrical.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  132w   REG               0,50    18261    1414518 /var/www/vhosts/thedailydiscourse.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  133w   REG               0,50        0    1414496 /var/www/vhosts/thedailydiscourse.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  134w   REG               0,50        0    4614848 /var/www/vhosts/test.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  135w   REG               0,50        0    4614792 /var/www/vhosts/test.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  136w   REG               0,50        0    5114460 /var/www/vhosts/valvanocarpeting.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  137w   REG               0,50        0    5114477 /var/www/vhosts/valvanocarpeting.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  138w   REG               0,50      338    5000735 /var/www/vhosts/ip.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  139w   REG               0,50        0    5000678 /var/www/vhosts/ip.iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  140w   REG               0,50     3235    1407620 /var/www/vhosts/cincyartgroup.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  141w   REG               0,50        0    1407569 /var/www/vhosts/cincyartgroup.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  142w   REG               0,50    37248    1395450 /var/www/vhosts/chicagolandanswering.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  143w   REG               0,50        0    1395399 /var/www/vhosts/chicagolandanswering.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  144w   REG               0,50    61580    4614296 /var/www/vhosts/atcanswers.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  145w   REG               0,50        0    4614238 /var/www/vhosts/atcanswers.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  146w   REG               0,50      809    1333992 /var/www/vhosts/iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  147w   REG               0,50        0    1333945 /var/www/vhosts/iandpdev.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  148w   REG               0,50   100684    1392225 /var/www/vhosts/ideasandpixels.com/statistics/logs/access_log
httpd   20034 apache  149w   REG               0,50     4912    1392174 /var/www/vhosts/ideasandpixels.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log
httpd   20034 apache  150w   REG               0,50        0    1316345 /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the `top` output? What have you done so far to try to resolve the problem?

Comment: What evidence do you have that high CPU is causing your server to crash? These are not normally related. What analysis have you done to confirm the problem? Investigate the cause? Why do you think then open lg files have anything to do with the problem? Voting to close this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I couldn't include it, was above the limit. I took out anything that seemed less important so it would fit.

Symcbean: None, really. I've really tried to investigate this for weeks now, if not months. Please don't try to close something that I need help with.

Answer (score 1):

What are the errors you find in the log files? check for connections from repeated IP addresses and see if they're from your customers. Check for any `defunct` process.

I faced a high cpu usage issue in my apache server few days back, web crawling from `Baiduspider, Yandex.ru, Majestic.co.uk` caused more traffic to the web server. As we don't have any customers from China/Russia, I had to block them using `robots.txt`, `.htaccess` and few other IP addresses using `Iptables`. After I blocked the bots the system usage went below.

Just wanted to share my experience. This might not be same for you.